# Sum Result in List RoundResult in List HomPlayerResult

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, foreach

Hi I wan't to get the sum of Results in my list of `HomPlayerResult.RoundResults.Result`

For each `HomePlayerResult` have a list of `RoundResult` where Table is 1, 2, 3 or 4.

```
var H1R1 = matchResult.HomePlayerResults.ToList().ForEach(y => y.RoundResults.ToList().ForEach(z => z.Round == 1 && z.Table == 1));
```

But I get error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Avoid `...ToList().ForEach`. It's normally a code smell

Comment: Remove `var H1R1 =` and try again.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me, but are you looking for this?:  `matchResult.HomePlayerResults.SelectMany(y => y.RoundResults).Count(z => z.Round == 1 && z.Table == 1)`

Comment: What you are trying to calculate - sum of `z.Round` or sum of `z.Table`?

Comment: In each  RoundResult there is z.Result so. When an player in the list of HomeTeamPlayer hav result in Round 1 and Table 1, i wan´t sum of z.Result.

Comment: In each  RoundResult there is z.Result so. When an player in the list of HomeTeamPlayer have result in Round 1 and Table 1, i w´ll get  sum of z.Result.
Beacuse It´s 2 player att each round at each Table get result. It could be HomeTeamResult 0 or 1 or 1. HomeTeamPlayer  8 is substituet for one or anothewr player in that round and Table. But not in Round == 1

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you are doing in your code but I believe that you want to get sum of round results out from all the results by filtering them on round 1 and table 1:

```
var H1R1 = matchResult.HomePlayerResults.Where(r => z.Round == 1 && z.Table == 1).Select(z => z.RoundResults).Sum();
```

1. Where condition is filtering list by round 1 and table 1
2. Next I selected round results out from filtered list and summarized